# Call stored procedure in PHP using sqlsrv driver

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm trying to call procedure in PHP using SQLSRV driver of Microsoft. Here is my stored procedure, calling function. But it shows me an error:

> "Error in executing statement. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP
>   [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid
>   parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid
>   parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )"

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getRelatedProductById]
    (@productId int)
AS
BEGIN
    declare
        @id varchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

BEGIN TRY
    select @id = relatedProduct   
    from Product 
    where id = @productId

    set @sql = 'select * from Product where id in(' + @id + ')' +'and id != '+ Convert(varchar, @productId)
    exec sp_executesql @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, 
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, 
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, 
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure, 
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, 
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    select @@error
    print @@error
END CATCH
END

-- exec getRelatedProductById 1
```

PHP function:

```
public function getRelatedProduct($cid,$productId,$limit) {
    $db=new db();
    settype($productId, "integer");
    $params = array(array($productId, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));
    $callSP = "{CALL getRelatedProductById(?)}";
    $sql=sqlsrv_query($db, $callSP,$params);
    if( $sql === false )
        {
             echo "Error in executing statement.\n";
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `sqlsrv_query` expects as first argument resource from `sqlsrv_connect` function but you are passing instance of some mysterious class `db`. Maybe you should use variable `$cid` instead `$db` (`$db` and `$limit` seem unnecessary in your function).

```
$sql = sqlsrv_query($cid, $callSP, $params);
```

Comment: Hi @kba, Your answer is right but not in my scenario but I got solution from your suggestion. Thanks